# Fixed positioning not at the top of current page view

Tags: css

When i use fixed position, it goes to the very top of the entire page - not the current page viewport. So if i scroll to the middle of the page and trigger a popup i would like the fixed overlay to stick to the top of the browser window:

Click view video:
https://getfarmacy.com/collections/frontpage/products/morning-routine

Please help!

I have tried top: 0; position: fixed;  -webkit-transform: none !important;

and it doesnt work. Please note this is shopify and [tachyons](http://tachyons.io/).

```js
//Video 
// Initiate FitVid.js
$(".video-container").fitVids();

// Iframe/player variables
var iframe = $('#video')[0];
var player = $f(iframe);

// Open on play
$('.play').click(function() {
  //$("body").addClass("is-visible");
  $('.overlay').css('left', 0)
  $('.overlay').addClass('show')
  player.api("play");
})

// Closes on click outside
$('.overlay').click(function() {
  $('.overlay').removeClass('show');
  $("body").removeClass("is-visible");
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.overlay').css('left', '-100%')
  }, 300);
  player.api("pause");
})
```

```css
  .overlay {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  left: -100%;
  transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: none;
  -webkit-transform: none !important;
}

.video-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transform: none;
  -webkit-transform: none !important;
}

.close {
  width: 20px;
  fill: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  /* Bring above video */
  top: -30px;
}

.close:hover {
  /* 50% opacity white */
  fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Class to fade in overlay */

.show {
  opacity: 1;
```

```html
<section id="module-video" class="video db w-100 mv5 relative">
  <div class="db tc" data-aos="fade-in">
    <h1 class="f3 db w-100 mt4 mb4-l mb2">{{ block.settings.product_video_title }}</h1>
    <div class="db tc mw8 center flex items-end justify-center">
      {% if block.settings.product_video_image %}
      <img class="w-100" src="{{ block.settings.product_video_image  | img_url: '972x469' }}"> {% else %}
      <img class="w-100" src="{{ 'video.jpg' | asset_url }}"> {% endif %}
      <span class="play mb5 white fw1 flex items-center justify-center ttu  absolute bottom-1"><img class="pr3" src="{{ 'play.svg' | asset_url }}">View Video</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="video-container">
      <!-- SVG Close (X) Icon -->
      <svg class="close" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="39.2 22.3 25 24.5"><path d="M39.5,46.4c0.2,0.2,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.4c0.3,0,0.6-0.1,0.9-0.4l10.3-10.3L62,46.4c0.2,0.2,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.4c0.3,0,0.6-0.1,0.9-0.4c0.5-0.5,0.5-1.3,0-1.8L53.5,34.3l9.8-9.8c0.5-0.5,0.5-1.3,0-1.8c-0.5-0.5-1.3-0.5-1.8,0l-9.8,9.8l-9.8-9.8c-0.5-0.5-1.3-0.5-1.8,0c-0.5,0.5-0.5,1.3,0,1.8l9.8,9.8L39.5,44.6C39,45.1,39,45.9,39.5,46.4z"/></svg>

      <!-- Embedded video -->
      <iframe id="video" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/29544927?api=1" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



}
```

Comment: It needs to have a positioned parent, so it know "according to what" should it position itself. If you add your code to the example (which you should have in the first place), I can show you exactly where is the catch. But try to add `position: relative` to its parent.

Comment: Baitclick. This question seems to be advertisment.

Comment: No its not sorry i just needed to show an example of what im dealing with. The problem with position relative is that its still not sticked to the top of the page.

Comment: You need to provide a complete code. Not just css, because it's not enough. I can inspect the page and see HTML structure, but it's not "my job". When asking questions on SO, try to provide as much relevant info as needed and you are much more likely to get a fast answer. So, please update the question with HTML and css code.

Comment: Then, please check again for the link you provide. It redirects to https://getfarmacy.com/password There is nothing in the page as you said.

Comment: Thank you guys!! Updated the code, and there is no password needed to access now. Seriously appreciate the help.

Comment: You can try to set `height: 100%;` to the div `<div class="overlay show">` and `top: 800px;` to the div `<div class="video-container">`.

Comment: The quickest "fix" is to offset top value for the height or the top navigation bar. So, set `.overlay` to `top: -81px;`. As to why it is happening, I am still inspecting the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick fix would be simply to offset the top value on `.overlay` by the height of the header. In your case: 81px;

```
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: -81px; /* hack, fix, it gets the job done */
}
```

But, I was looking at the documentation and found this. The actual problem was that you have `transform: translate3D` set to the `.page-container`. If you remove transform, your problem with (children's) fixed position is gone.

Documentation:
[Types of positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Types_of_positioning)

> An absolutely positioned element is an element whose computed position value is absolute or fixed. The top, right, bottom, and left properties specify offsets from the edges of the element's containing block. (The containing block is the ancestor relative to which the element is positioned.) If the element has margins, they are added to the offset.

Well, let's see what it says about the [containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block):

> If the position property is absolute or fixed, the containing block may also be formed by the edge of the padding box of the nearest ancestor element that has the following:
>
> 1. transform or perspective value other than none (that's our guy)

[Identifying the containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block#Identifying_the_containing_block)

Comment: Wow!! Thank you, I have been looking at this issue for hours and I did not catch that. You are a true hero!!!